# The Plutus script evaluation failed

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cardano-cli, transaction

Running into this error when attempting to build a tx.

````
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 1 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: 6228000431
| mem: -2515
})
Script debugging logs: 
the script for policyId 0 (in the order of the PolicyIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: 6209175329
| mem: -4312
})```

Any ideas for how to solve it?
````

Answer (score 1):

Had to use `cardano-cli transaction build-raw` and set my scripts to use more memory and cpu via the following flags (for example):

```
--tx-in-execution-units="(5000000000, 5000000)" \
   ...
--mint-execution-units="(5000000000, 5000000)" \
```

I used the following divisions as they add up to the maximum tx mem and cpu units for testnet (as of 11/24/2021) and split the units halfway between both of them, since both scripts were failing.